# Electron App with Flash Player After Flash End Of Life In 2021

Tags: node.js, flash, electron, adobe, eof

I am new with electron and using flash in my electron app to run an old flash studio app (a site that contains .swf files and run with nodejs).
The app is only for local use, working with `pepflashplayer64_32_0_0_433.dll`.
Right now, it is working perfectly. How can I ensure that the app will run properly after the flash player end of life in 2021?

Comment: Please check the solution outlined here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65254243/does-the-flash-executable-itself-stop-flash-from-working-january-12-2021/65685790#65685790

Answer (score 0):

try changing your Microsoft Windows date to 1/13/2021 to test the display of the blocking message that Adobe embedded in the dll

Answer (score 0):

you can use FP version 32.0.0.371 which is without the time bomb
btw do you have any link of your electron app? I wish to build one for some flash apps too thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Ruffle](https://github.com/ruffle-rs/ruffle) project, a Flash player native simulator made in Rust->WebAssembly, which is dual-licensed under the MIT license and Apache license, version 2.0. It's close to being mature.

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. You should [explain why and how it solves the problem, and provide code on how to use it](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.